# Align button horizontally center in the page

Tags: html, css, button

How can i align button at center of html body. Any one help me

[Page View of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxwnv.png)

Comment: Could you give us some code ? We cannot really help you here.

Comment: @Xogno so true :P

Answer (score 2):

You can give the button the following CSS code:

```
button{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can also use flexbox on the container of the button:

```
.container{
display: flex;
}
```

You can then use the following:

```
button{
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The display:flex worked for me.

Comment: Quick note: flexboxes aren't fully supported by every browser:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score -2):

Here you go, basic one. You didn't provide a code so we can't provide an answer using your code.

```css
body {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<button>center</button>
```

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain?

Comment: Probably because they felt this was a low-quality answer. Telling OP to upvote/accept your question probably doesn't help either.